# xpath expression - select element where parent contains a specific text

Tags: html, firefox, xpath

I struggle currently to find the correct xpath expression to select an input element where its parent/sibling element contains a specific text.

In the example below, I would like to select the "input" element where, in the same `tr` row, a `td` element with a specific text exists.

**my example path** - returns no match

```
//input[contains(../../../td/text(),"15-935-331")]
```

**source code**

```
<tr>
    <td><a href="xxx" target="_blank">xxxx, yyyyy</a></td>
    <td>Mr</td>
    <td></td>
    <td> 15-935-331</td>
    <form id="betreuerModel" action="xxxx" method="POST">
      <td class="tRight">
        <input value="Bearbeiten" id="bearbeiten" name="bearbeiten" class="submit" title="Bearbeiten" type="submit"/>
      </td>
    </form>
</tr>
<tr>
 // .. next row with same structure
</tr>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `contains` function, when given a nodeset, will only operate on the very first node in that nodeset. In your case, it is `<td><a href="xxx" target="_blank">xxxx, yyyyy</a></td>`.
You could instead refactor your expression so that the predicate operates on all the nodes to check, and the `contains` function operates on a single item:

```
//input[../../../td/text()[contains(., "15-935-331")]]
```

This will get any `input` element, where the parent's parent's parent contains a `td` element with a text node containing the text `15-935-331`.

---

A perhaps easier way to specify this would be to use `ancestor::tr[1]/td` in place of `../../../td`.

```
//input[ancestor::tr[1]/td/text()[contains(.,"15-935-331")]]
```

This would get the first `tr` in the ancestor hierarchy, and operate on that.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to the solution posted by Keith, you can use the following XPath expression:

```
//tr[td[contains(., "15-935-331")]]/form//input
```

This makes it a bit more independent of the actual structure of the HTML. It selects the `tr` which contains a `td` containing the given text, and from that `tr` it takes the `input` element anywhere below the `form` element.